# Rearranging HTML and Importing into Access

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

**The Problem:**

I have a bunch of HTML with multiple tables, two of which are of interest (posted above).  The first table describes a person, their address, phone number, and so on.  The second table describes information about their account.  Both tables have headers (text in `<h3></h3>` tags) through which they can be referenced.
I am relatively new to manipulating HTML and so my first question is how someone goes about taking the first table and importing it into an Access database or into Excel so that if they had 50 of these documents the columns would
be, in this example, Name, Address, Phone, Age, with each row being a different person.

My second question is slightly more complicated.  The second table has another table embedded in it.  Essentially this means that there are lots of smaller split up tables that need to be put into one complete table.  That is, I am hoping to find a way to treat it as an additional column in the main table (the one actually given its own header)
housing this smaller table.  The idea would be to then manipulate this table in the same way as the first table.  The final problem is that these tables don't have a common field that I can use to relate them, so there would need to be a way to take
a field from the first table and append it to the second table.  Considering this, I think the steps needed can be summarized as follows:

> 1. For a single HTML document take the second table and perform the
>      actions necessary to append the smaller table's  tag and
>      the main table's  `<th colspan="7"></th>` to the section formatted
>      as

```
`<tr> <td style="text-align: center;">1</td> <td
style="text-align: center;">10/2013</td> <td style="text-align:
center;">12345678</td> <td style="text-align: right;">0167</td> <td
    style="text-align: center;">10/2014</td> <td style="text-align:
right;">0036</td> <td style="text-align: center;">1111</td>   </tr>`
```

> ```
> so that all 9 pieces of data get their own column upon import.
>
> 2. Take the column whose <th></th> tags contain the string "Name" and add it as the first column in the second table.
>
> 3. Import the first table's <td></td> tags to Access.
>
> 4. Import the second table's now revised <td></td> tags to Access.
>
> 5. Repeat for all HTML documents so that there are two complete tables.
> ```

**The HTML:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Customer File</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
          body { width: 800px; margin: 40px auto; font-family: Verdana; }
          h1 { font-size: 18pt; margin-bottom: 20px; }
          h2 { font-size: 14pt; margin-bottom: 20px; }
          h3 { font-size: 11pt; text-decoration: underline; margin-bottom: 20px; }
          th { text-align: left; }
          hr { height: 1px; border: none; margin: 20px 0; color: #ccc; background-color: #ccc; }
          .text { font-size: 10pt; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>


      <!--FIRST TABLE--> 

    <h3>Customer</h3>
            <table class="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 12em;">Name</th>
                <td>Tom Thompson</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Address</th>
                <td>123 St., Vancouver, BC, V6Z 2M7</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <td>555-555-1233</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>Date of Birth, Age</th>
                <td>03/04/1985, 29</td>
              </tr>
            </table>

       <!-- SECOND TABLE--> 

            <h3>Collection</h3>
            <table class="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 640px;">
              <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center;">#</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Date Purchased</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Product Name</th>
                <th style="text-align: right;">$</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Date of Product Procurement</th>
                <th style="text-align: right;">Item Number</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Order Number</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="7">
                  <br />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="7">VALUE MENU</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">05/10/2013</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">Hamburger</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">4.50</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">01/10/2013</td>
                <td style="text-align: right;">0005</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">5678345</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="7">
                  <table class="text" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                      <th style="width: 10em;">Cashier Name</th>
                      <td>Sam Johnson</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Access so you are on windows. Have a look at the [html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

It makes parsing and splitting html almost fun to do :-)

For use from VBA I suggest to implement the functionality in VB.NET or C# and expose the resulting API through COM, consumable by VBA.
Other option is perhaps the creation of an AddIn by using VSTO in either VB.NET or C#

[Article on codeplex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555660/Extend-your-VBA-code-with-Csharp-VB-NET-or-Cpluspl) on exposing .NET code through COM interfaces to consume by VBA can be a starrting point.

Comment: @iboshuizen Is it possible to use this in conjunction with VBA?

Comment: @iboshuizen This is a bit embarrassing, but I think you may be overestimating my knowledge of the connections between VB.NET and VBA.  How does one 'expose the resulting API through COM'?

Comment: Embarrassing? Not true, see it as an opportunity to gain knowledge. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to open HTML file in EXCEL by COM automation and read info into MS Access by `ActiveSheet.Cells(row,col)`